# Echo Death, obscure novel from 1972?

Tags: story-identification, novel, science, teleportation

Can anyone help to find the exact title and author of a novel I read in 1972? It was checked out of a library, and I believe it was a new release at the time, though I may be wrong about that. I remember the title being *Echo Death*, but have had no luck finding a book by that title. The story line was about a man with the innate ability to teleport. He was acting as a eco-warrior type character fighting against the "establishment" in a dystopian future world in ecological disaster. There was a antagonist hunting him who also had the ability to teleport. In the end, the protagonist realizes that he had a death experience years before and that his ability to teleport allowed him to jump from it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is [Ecodeath](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25050571-ecodeath) (1972) by William Jon Watkins & E. V. Snyder.

> An ecoescape story about Watkins and Snyder (when they weren't writing this book) who both can "Jump" into time. Watkins has lost his wife and child to the poison bloom of one Ashley's firm and is determined to get him; Ashley hires Snyder to kill Watkins, but before they're through Jumping through time and space, they're collaborating as they did at the typewriter.
>
> <sub><sup>[Kirkus Reviews](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/william-jon-e-v-snyder-watkins/ecodeath/)</sup></sub>

[image]

Comment: I'd be surprised if this weren't it. +1

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. That is it! I never thought to do a search as a single word, or that it was "eco" and not "echo".

Comment: For the record, I found this by going to [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/) and searching for titles with the word "death" in them, then just scrolling along to the letter e.